# Как разметить два div блока так чтобы если второй не появляется первый растягивался на всю ширину?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Нужно 2 блока разместить так, чтобы когда второй блок не выводится сайтом, то первый растягвиается на  всю имеющуюся область, как так сделать? на скрине показала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно div (ам) которые внутри задать
flex: 1 1 auto
Div обертка display flex

```css
.one {
  border: 3px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.two {
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
.wrap {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
</div>
```